# Manter checkbox selecionada por padrão

Tags: html, checkbox

Como posso fazer para a minha checkbox aparecer checada para todo mundo que entrar no site uma vez que ela foi checada? Estou criando no campo de html do wix, versão gratuita.

O modelo de código que estou usando é o seguinte

```
<form name=myform>
  <input type="checkbox" name=mybox value="1">Trocar  a água dos balde<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name=mybox value="2">Verificar balheiro<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name=mybox value="3">Espirrar herbal<br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 7):

Para deixar o `checkbox` marcado como por padrão, basta adicionar o atributo `checked` ao elemento.

Exemplo:

```html
    <form name=myform>
      <input type="checkbox" name=mybox value="1" checked>Trocar  a água dos balde<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name=mybox value="2">Verificar balheiro<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name=mybox value="3" checked>Espirrar herbal<br>
    </form>
```